# Disabling log messages in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to disable log messages in QGIS Dufour?

When I work in QGIS 2.0, log messages increase to more than 2000 and it makes QGIS very slow. Then I save project and open it again, then QGIS work fine and everything is fast. But during work in QGIS, logged messages iNcrease and it works slowly.

Here I have enclosed the screen shot of the log messages from QGIS[image: Log messages from QGIS]

Comment: Sounds like an issue which hasn't come to the developers' attention yet. Please file a bug report.

Comment: What are the loads of messages about?  And does it help to close the tabls in the message viewer once in a while?

Comment: I think the problem must be related to why you have so many log messages. Can you tell us what are those messages about?